# Surge in new users on my website, are they fake?

Tags: email, dotnetnuke-7

Sorry if this is the wrong exchange.

Ok I have had my DotNetNuke website up for awhile now but no man users signing up. After speaking to one users it seems that my skin was a little poor in terms of logging in/registering as rather than the usual 2 buttons my skin just had a '+'

Anyway I changed my skin so I now have a clear 'Login' and 'Register' button. Over 24 hours or so I suddenly had a load of new users (40+). Checking my email inbox I seem to have quite a few Delivery errors for most of these users with errors like so.

`Failed Recipient: @gmail.com
Reason: Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 ay8si26335412wib.67 - gsmtp`

or

`Failed Recipient: @live.de
Reason: Remote host said: 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable`

and another

`Failed Recipient: @gawab.com
Reason: Failed to connect to the recipients mail server.  No DNS information was found for the 'gawab.com' domain.`

this one says fake account???

`Failed Recipient: @yahoo.com
Reason: Remote host said: 554 delivery error: dd This user doesn't have a yahoo.com account (@yahoo.com) [0] - mta1153.mail.gq1.yahoo.com`

Obviously I have removed the start of the email address for posting here.

So my question is what is the cause of these errors?
Is it DNN and some settings?
Is it my mail server? - using SmarterMail
Are they just fake accounts?

If they are fake accounts is there anyway I can better prevent them?

Comment: The addresses above authoritatively do not exist so someone/people are making them up.  Look at the spread of IP addresses attempting signups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a recent exploit by spammers who figured out how to script automated registrations on DNN websites.  I was getting 20-40 of these per day on my DNN sites also.  There is a way to address this.  Follow the steps described in the following articles:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154984/spammer-registrations

OR

http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/300/2-Strategies-on-how-to-deal-with-DNN-Registration-Spam-Part-1-3.aspx

Comment: I stumbled upon similar posts which helps me solve the issue but I have marked this as the answer for other users.